# Histogram Memory Allocation Failure

Tags: histograms

I have a list of 3256 pairs of data with which I plotted a scatter plot, no problem. But when I tried to take the ratio with the two elements of each pair and do a Histogram of the ratios, I got a Memory Allocation Failure. Please help.

```
ListPlot[ABC]

Histogram[MapThread[
 If[#2 == 0 || #1 == 0, 0, #1/#2] &, {ABC[[All, 1]], ABC[[All, 2]]}]
```

Comment: After adding a missing `]` to the end of the `Histogram` command, it gives me a histogram.

Comment: Note that `{ABC[[All, 1]], ABC[[All, 2]]}` can be simplified to `Transpose@ABC`

Comment: Yes, I did and got a failure message {{0.23952802767859183`,-0.009204347181706707`},.....,{0.17591561029000724`,-\
0.00022068331696986653`},<<3206>>} cannot be transposed. >>

Comment: @ZMingMa - then there is a problem in your data. What do you get when you evaluate `DeleteCases[ABC, {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}]`? You should get an empty list `{ }`

Comment: I got this instead    \!\(
TagBox[
RowBox[{"{", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"Inverse", "[", 
RowBox[{"{", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"{", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "0"}], "}"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"{", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "0"}], "}"}]}], "}"}], "]"}], ".", 
RowBox[{............
RowBox[{"{", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"{", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "0"}], "}"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"{", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "0"}], "}"}]}], "}"}], "]"}], ".", 
RowBox[{"{", 
RowBox[{"0.`", ",", "0.`"}], "}"}]}]}], "}"}],
Short[#, 
Rational[5, 2]]& ]\)

Comment: @ZMingMa - When responding to a comment, address the response using the form `@name`. Your data does not consist of just pairs of data. At a minimum clean the data. Preferably, fix it at the source of its generation.

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks for the suggestion. It turns out that the list includes some results from null matrix or noninvertable matrices. Am trying to find out how to get rid of them short of checking for complete zeros, such as If [ME==Null?